# Relay - RelayQueryWriter: Unexpectedly encountered `undefined` in payload

Tags: relayjs

I test relay, and I use relay-local-schema for test graph-ql request in client memory.

All are good, and when the sendQueries method is called I fetch the good data. I can check this in debug.

But after, I have this error message :

**RelayQueryWriter: Unexpectedly encountered `undefined` in payload. Cannot set root record `client:4122484501` to undefined.**

I don't understand the error message and it is very difficult for me to understand the problem.

I use typescript and tsx extentention.

thanks in advance, if you have any Idea for my problem

EDIT : RESOLVED

I make a mistake with the promise in the sendQuery method

with this all is better:

```js
sendQueries(queryRequests) { 
  return Promise.all(
    queryRequests.map(queryRequest => 
      graphql.graphql(
        this._schema,
        queryRequest.getQueryString(),
        this._rootValue,
        queryRequest.getVariables()
      ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          queryRequest.reject(new Error("..."));
        } else {
          queryRequest.resolve({response: result.data});
        }
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: if you have solved your own question, please either delete the question or post your solution as answer and accept it (share the knowledge)

Comment: solution goes below. answer section. accepting it tells people your problem is solved. its not very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a mistake with the promise in the sendQuery method.

I make a mistake with the promise in the sendQuery method

with this all is better:

```
sendQueries(queryRequests) { 
  return Promise.all(
    queryRequests.map(queryRequest => 
      graphql.graphql(
        this._schema,
        queryRequest.getQueryString(),
        this._rootValue,
        queryRequest.getVariables()
      ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          queryRequest.reject(new Error("..."));
        } else {
          queryRequest.resolve({response: result.data});
        }
      })
    )
  );
}
```

But I don't understand why I haved this error message : Relay - RelayQueryWriter: Unexpectedly encountered `undefined` in payload